# Trying to find element ('href') with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the URL ('href') of the below element in Python with Selenium. For the life of me it is not working, this is the only output I get is as an example:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="href"]"}
```

This is the element I want to get the ('Href') or ('Text') from:

[code.private.pri](https://code.private.pri)

Selector:
#tinymce > p:nth-child(20) > a

Xpath:
//*[@id="tinymce"]/p[7]/a

Full Xpath:
/html/body/p[7]/a

I tried the following methods to find the element on the page with no luck:

Selector
Xpath
Full Xpath

Only get: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: This is the path when inspecting the elekent on the webpage:

<p>
<a href="https://code.private.pri">https://code.private.pri</a>
</p>

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'get_attribute()' function to get the urls:

For example, if this XPath is correct - '`//*[@id="tinymce"]/p[7]/a`', then locator should be like this:

```
driver.fine_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tinymce']/p[7]/a").get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, tried you suggestion but unfortunately, it's also not working:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='tinymce']/p[7]/a"}

Comment: Your locator is wrong, use the correct locator.